# Is username + password functionally equivalent to a single login string of the same length?

Tags: authentication, passwords

My intuition is failing me with this. Would it make it easier or harder for an attacker trying to gain access to any of the accounts in a database?

I can see that in the case of a single login string, you're comparing it to all of the users in the database, as opposed to a particular one, so there's a greater chance you'll get a match for a random login. On the other hand, with username and password, if you're not interested in a particular user, you're also effectively comparing a single concatenated string to the whole database, except usernames are far less random than any part of a single randomly created login, so that feels like it would be less secure.

I guess what I'm really asking is whether claiming to be someone and demonstrating it is more secure than just demonstrating it.

Comment: It depends from how the login string is generated. If it's a string users manually enter, its entropy is probably not different from the entropy username + password have. On the other side, when the username is publicly shown, trying to gain access would just require to find the password.

Comment: It makes brute forcing a bit easier, since for example the String `Miner12345` could be an equivalent for the Username `Miner` and Pw `12345` but also for the Username `Mine` and Pw `r12345` and so on. Except ofc when the User and password Part of the password are devided by a (Special) character that cannot be used in the Username and Pw.

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusion of two aspects of a system / security of a system.

**Identity**

The modelling of a user in the system, usually uniquely identified as `username`.

This may not be a required feature of a system, although for a non-trivial system especially a secure system it is very important.

**Authentication**

The process and attributes related to the verification of the user in the system.

- Username / Password challenge process.
- 2nd factor challenge (mobile number).

**Other Parts: Authorisation**

The mechanism to allow a user access to (all or part) of a system. Which may be as simple as the implicit permission granted by creating the users account.

- Process to Grant access
- Process to Verify access.

**Now to answer the Question Itself:**

This method of authentication can be used for a simple resource see [Presigned URLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) where there is no requirement to know the user.

Or such URLS can also be used for a simple Single Use action that interacts with a System, such as in concert with a "reset password" email.

So for general repeatable access to a system this mechanism should not be used as  it is unlikely to be secure.

Comment: When re-reading the Question, another interpretation of the question might be for passwords that scan over all passwords to find a match to a given user. This is a dangerous design that fails to distinguish users. For example imagine two people choosing the same password, the login account is thus one of the two accounts?